# How to read a multidimensional array and store it in a pointer

Tags: c, file, pointers, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to write and read a `char` three dimensional array, or said in other words an array of strings arrays.

I've already try to allocate the memory in each part of the array, but it keeps failing with the following error: `Segment fault (core dumped)`

```
/**
 * Create array to write
 */
char writed[2][2][512] = {{"Hello", "World"}, {"Bye", "World"}};
/**
 * Allocate memory
 */
char *** readed = (char ***)malloc(sizeof(char **) *2 * 2 * 512);
for (int z = 0; z < 2; z++) {
    readed[z] = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char **) * 2 * 512 );
    for (int y = 0; y < 2; y++) {
        readed[z][y] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 512); 
    }
}    
/**
 * Write array
 */
FILE *writeFile = fopen("strings", "wb");
fwrite(writed, 2 * 2 * 512, 2 * 512, writeFile);
fclose(writeFile);
/**
 * Read array
 */
FILE *readFile = fopen("strings", "rb");
fread(readed, 2 * 2 * 512, 2 * 512, readFile);
fclose(readFile);
```

Comment: You dont need to allocate that much memory. You only need to multipy by the first number. That does not solve the problem but you should change that.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and then help you to debug it

Comment: It's already solved. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two different data structures here, each with a different layout.

`writed` is a 3 dimensional array of `char`, meaning that all of the memory of the array is contiguous.  In contrast, `readed` is a pointer to an array of `char **`, each of which points to an array of `char *,`each of which points to an array of `char`, and none of those need be continuous.

To have a similar data structure, you need declare `readed` as a pointer to a 2D array and allocate space for enough of those for a 3D array:

```
char (*readed)[2][512] = malloc(2 * sizeof(char[2][512]));
```

Also, [don't cast the return value of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

You're also writing / reading way more than you need to:

```
fwrite(writed, 2 * 2 * 512, 2 * 512, writeFile);
...
fread(readed, 2 * 2 * 512, 2 * 512, readFile);
```

This says you're reading / writing `2 * 512` elements, each of which has size `2 * 2 * 512`.  You're only reading/writing 1 member of that size:

```
fwrite(writed, 2 * 2 * 512, 1, writeFile);
...
fread(readed, 2 * 2 * 512, 1, readFile);
```

Comment: I tried to declare `readed` as you mention with out assign memory to each location of the array, but now the compiler fails with the error `free(): invalid pointer. Abort (core dumped)`

Comment: @DanielAlessandroAguilar You should only `free` what you `malloc`, specifically `free(readed)` only.

Comment: I'm not calling `free` function, I just change the pointer declaration and delete the `for` that allocate memory in every position.

Comment: @DanielAlessandroAguilar See my edit.  You're writing / reading too many bytes.

Comment: Thanks, your edit solve my problem, I've thinking that thrid parameter to `fread` / `fwrite` was the size on bytes of every element on the array.